# SSL and token when creating the mobile API

Tags: php, android, ios, security, ssl

I implement a security measurement in the mobile API in previous project.

That is , when the user login , the system generate a token and store it in the user record in database. Whenever the user send the request , they need to pass the token and compare it with the database one.

To prevent someone using other tool to post the data and pretend the others.

Now, in the new project, it use the SSL connection, if I understand it correctly, then it means the API only accept the request from the andorid/ IOS app. If that is true, then the token measurement is not need? Is it correct?

Thanks for helping

Comment: ssl does not mitergate the need to identify the user

Comment: yes but the user suppose can not modify the android/ IOS app to prevent the other user id?

Comment: no idea what you just said\asked

Comment: sorry for confusing you, that in API  there is a user_id pass from android / IOS app to server, if I don't implement the token measurement, the user can simply post the other user_id if he knows the api url and pretend to be other, is SSL can prevent that?

Comment: SSL can ensure the posting receive is from the app and user can not modify the app source code so the token measure is no longer necessary, is that true ? Thanks

Comment: no SSL does not prevent that, ssl stops any one between the app and the server getting the token. but does not stop a user changing the token sent from the app to the server